# How to create associative array of strings ( string[strings] ) from key-value file?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, d

Here example of associative array that I would like to get:

`string [string] rlist = ["dima":"first", "masha":"second", "roma":"third"];`

Text file that I read have very simple structure:

`peter = fourth
ivan = fifth
david = sixth`

```
string [string] strarr;    
string txt = readText("test.txt");
foreach (t;txt.splitLines())
{
    // ??
}
```

Could anybody suggest way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be me but I find it hard to reason about with a for loop and temp variables, I would rather do something like:

```
import std.conv;
import std.stdio;
import std.array;
import std.algorithm;

void main() {
    string[string] dic = File("test")
                              .byLine
                              .map!(l => l.to!string.findSplit(" = "))
                              .map!(l => tuple( l[0], l[2] ))
                              .assocArray;
}
```

byLine: read line by line, better than reading the whole thing and then splitting.

first map: split each line into three parts as explained by rcorre

second map: build pairs from the splitted lines

assocArray: build an associative array from those pairs.

Comment: nice modulo the use of `l`, the worst variable name ever

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
  import std.string : splitLines, strip;
  import std.file : readText;
  import std.algorithm : findSplit;

  string[string] strarr;
  string txt = readText("test.txt");

  foreach(t ; txt.splitLines()) {
    auto res = t.findSplit("=");
    string key = res[0].strip;
    string val = res[2].strip;
    strarr[key] = val;
  }
```

[`findSplit`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_searching.html#.findSplit) will return three ranges: the part before '=', '=', and the part after '='. [`strip`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_string.html#.strip) can be used to remove whitespace around the = that would otherwise be included in the key and value.

If you want a more robust solution, you could consider a D library for reading config/ini files like [onyx-config](http://code.dlang.org/packages/onyx-config), [ctini](http://code.dlang.org/packages/ctini), or [dini](http://code.dlang.org/packages/dini).